# Artists, plagiators and beholders

Tags: shirk

There are artists, some do poor work, some do great work.
And there are the beholders and buyers that praise, enjoy and pay for that work.

And then, there are palgiators, reproducing original artwork or extending it.

Now some *beholders* as I choose to call them will get near ecstasy for some artwork, but will get really disappointed if it turns out it has not been made by their famous artist but by someone else.

I call this idolatry, shirk, as they do not value the work, but the artist.

What is the Islamic view on this?

Comment: Why do you consider valuing the artist to be shirk but valuing the work not shirk? Neither of them are Allah.

Comment: @goldPseudo can we value things that are not Allah? I value a good meal, a lazy afternoon. My point is to make an artists work *depend* on who created it.

Comment: @goldPseudo think of some rich snob buying a painting he has been told was done by a famous artist. Then it turns out it has been made by some half-grown but gifted kid from the neighborhood. The painting stays the same, looks the same. But it was not done by the buyers idol.